# How to resize LVM /home and /usr partitions

Tags: partitioning, debian, lvm

I need to increase the space on my /usr partition, however I cannot shrink my /home partition, as the manager requires unmounting, which cannot happen while the system is running.  I am running Debian Wheezy on an i686 intel processor.  I have all LVM partitions placed inside an encrypted partition.

Comment: If you login in single user or without gui as root, then nothing on /home should be accessed, which will let you unmount it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boot on a live CD and resize your partitions in live mode. So you ensure that nothing is mounted.

Comment: Hi Danduk82, welcome to Superuser! We are a site that requires professional answers, such that the user can read your instructions and follow it to make it work. Can you describe the steps in more detail?

Comment: I already did just that, and now it is resolved.  Thank you!

Comment: @CanadianLuke Ok, sorry. I'll be more clear next time.